# Identifying a connection after SNAT

Tags: networking, load-balancing, nat

Hi I have a problem statement that I am trying to solve from quite a while now.

Problem Statement (This is a networking scenario):
Machine A and Machine B want to connect to Machine D, Machine C being a Load Balancer between them. At Machine D I want to determine which connection came from Machine A and which connection came from Machine B.

As the load balancer will use a single IP to SNAT all the connections coming from Machine A and Machine B.

Why I want to solve this ?
Consider that there is a Machine Z that is a malicious machine and it tries to connect to Machine D, I want to control all the incoming connections to this machine.

Essentially , there are to connections happening for every request from A to D.

1. Machine A to Machine C
2. Machine C to Machine D

Is there something common in the tcp/ip packets of these two connections that can be used as an identifier?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a layer 7 load balancer, and the network traffic supports it, the load balancer can insert clues to the traffic about the source address (for example, HTTP reverse proxyes usually add the `X-Forwarded-For` header, which contains the original caller address).

On lower levels, you have no clue about the source of the package you got, since any kind of NAT modifies the IP header.

It might worth mentioning that in scenarios like yours, all filtering should be done on the load balancer, or before that, and not on the backend servers. The backend servers should not care about packet filtering and source identification (other than application-level purposes perhaps).

Comment: Okay ,are you suggesting that the filtering part of this scenario should be the load balancers job? I should not worry about it at the end point?

Comment: Either on the load balancer, or on a firewall in front of the loadbalancer.

Comment: Okay thanks for suggestion but is there a field in the packets 
of these connections which is common / identifier?                                                               1) Machine A to Machine C                                                                       2) Machine C to Machine D

Comment: If the load balancer is performing NAT at layer 4, there is no way you can know (on the server) where the connections actually come from. If instead it's working as a reverse proxy (at layer 7), it can insert HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks, does the ID field in IP header survive after SNAT?

Comment: I've seen it to survive, however, I did not really gave much thought of it. You shouldn't either in this case, as per [RFC 6864](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6864), 4.1: _"The IPv4 ID field MUST NOT be used for purposes other than fragmentation and reassembly."_

Answer (score 0):

You could make it by inspecting IP packet fields. For example, you could change TTL or set DSCP at source machine and check it at destination.
There are some limitations here, though - TTL change would work if you know how far (in hops) your "valid" machines are.

Comment: Thanks, Does id the ID field in IP header survive after SNAT?

Comment: @Raghavkaushik, check out here: https://www.cellstream.com/reference-reading/tipsandtricks/314-the-purpose-of-the-ip-id-field-demystified